# 13.10 Onscreen Keyboard suddenly stopped working

Tags: mouse, onscreen-keyboard

My Onscreen keyboard suddenly stopped working. I click with mouse but it's not writing any more. Not sure where is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reinstall your `onboard` application by running the below command on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall onboard
```

Now it will work.